# Как в slim правильно написать "end.empty"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ранее для вывода сообщения об отсутствии записей я использовал это:

```
end.empty? and begin
```

Но в slim такое не прокатило. Выдало не просто сообщение о неправильном синтаксисе, а напрочь положило проект. В консоле написало лишь:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Explicit end statements are forbidden):

Как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что не так с обычным ифом? Он и попонятнее будет:

```
- if @items.any? # Или другой предикат на ваш вкус
  = render @items
- else
  i Ничего нет
```

А можно ещё агрессивнее разбить на частичные шаблончики, и пользуясь фактом, что для пустой коллекции `render` вернёт `nil` (в [гайдах](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) об этом есть), сделать так:

```
= render(@items) || render("no_items")
```